# Symfony and Doctrine - displaying data from database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to display data from database.

This is my routing:

```
pages:
    pattern: /pages/{id}
    defaults:
       _controller: DprocMainBundle:Index:show
```

This is the method for that route:

```
public function showAction($id)
    {
        $page = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('DprocMainBundle:Pages')
           ->find($id);

        if (!$page) {
           throw $this->createNotFoundException('No product found for id '.$id);
        }
        return $this->render('DprocMainBundle:Dproc:single.html.twig',array('pages' => $page));
    }
```

print_r($page) displays:

```
Dproc\MainBundle\Entity\Pages Object
(
    [Id:protected] => 1
    [page_title:protected] => A Foo Bar
    [page_content:protected] => Test content for page
    [page_category:protected] => 3dsmax
)
```

In single.html.twig im trying to display that information:

```
{% for page in pages %}
    {{ page.page_title }}
{% endfor %}
```

It shows nothing, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it ok that you iterate on a single result? why not {{pages.page_title}} without 'for'?

Comment: Sure but - Method "page_title" for object "Dproc\MainBundle\Entity\Pages" does not exist in DprocMainBundle:Dproc:single.html.twig

Comment: I did it by getter method {{ page.getPageTitle }}

Answer (score 0):

The method `find()` will just return a single result, not an array. If you did `findBy(array('id'=>$id))` then you would get an array back with one result. Alternatively you could just not loop through in your template because there's no need when you have only one result. Just change your variable name to page and use `{{ page.page_title }}`

Comment: The variable name is pages, when i try {{ pages.page_title }} it shows   Method "page_title" for object "Dproc\MainBundle\Entity\Pages" does not exist in DprocMainBundle:Dproc:single.html.twig

Comment: when i try page.page_title it tells that page variable doesnt exist

Comment: I did it by getter method {{ page.getPageTitle }}

Comment: If you have a `getPageTitle()` method in your `Page` entity, you can call `{{ page.pageTitle }}` in your twig template. And this works for every `get()` functions.

Comment: You may need to show some of the code from your Pages entity. Is the title variable just called title possibly?

Answer (score 0):

You used two differents entity.. one is in `getRepository('DprocMainBundle:Pages')` and other is in render('DprocMainBundle:`Dproc`:single.html.twig',array('pages' => $page)). You should put there the same entity i.e `DprocMainBundle:Pages` . I hope this you success.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the for loop. Because you have post data from the database, you can try this:

```
{{ pages.page_title }}
```